# Json Deserialization for array of objects and dynamic pair key values zoho forms

Tags: c#, json, api, zoho

I have trying to convert zoho forms reponse to c# object. The response json contains dynamic key with nested array objects.

Sample response output from zoho:

```
var jsonString = "{\n  \"result\": [\n    {\n      \"726468000000236142\": [\n        {\n          \"EmailID\": \"tiaburmen@zylker.com\",\n          \"CreatedTime\": \"1671092494538\" \n        }\n      ]\n    },\n    {\n        \"726468000000236143\": [\n        {\n          \"EmailID\": \"tiaburmen1@zylker.com\",\n          \"CreatedTime\": \"16710192494538\" \n        }\n      ] \n    }\n  ]\n}";
```

tried code :

```
 var finalResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonString);

    var valueList = finalResult["result"];
    foreach(var item in valueList)
    {
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);
        var dictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,object>>(json);
        var json2 =  JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictionary);
        
        //var json3 =  JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictionary2);
        Console.WriteLine(dictionary["726468000000236142"].selectToken("EmailID"));
    }
```

Fiddle: (Working Version)
https://dotnetfiddle.net/CprVGw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the JSON string you gave, you can change your object class to

```
public class Root
{
    public List<Dictionary<string, List<People>>> Result { get; set; }
}
```

then you can deserialize it by

```
var finalResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonString);
foreach (var item in finalResult.Result)
{
    foreach (var key in item.Keys)
    {
        //726468000000236142
        Console.WriteLine(key);
        foreach (var people in item[key])
        {
            Console.WriteLine(people.EmailID);
        }
    }
}
```